# Android performance of static variable or property

Tags: android, variables, static, public

Hi i want to know what is better in terms of performance for the use of  static values in Android.

1- Create a public static variable in a class

```
public static boolean _loadConfiguration = true;
```

or

2- Create a get/set public static property in a class

```
private static boolean _loadConfiguration = true;

public static boolean LoadConfiguration() {
    return _loadConfiguration;
}

public static void LoadConfiguration(boolean loadConfiguration) {
    _loadConfiguration = loadConfiguration;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [Android: Designing for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html), it's a great article.

In short, they benchmarked the system with [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/), and got to the conclusion that you souhld [Avoid Internal Getters/Setters](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#internal_get_set):

"Without a JIT, direct field access is about **3x faster** than invoking a trivial getter. With the JIT (where direct field access is as cheap as accessing a local), direct field access is about **7x faster** than invoking a trivial getter. This is true in Froyo, but will improve in the future when the JIT inlines getter methods."

Comment: Rotemmiz: So you say that is better to use the option 1: boolean xvalue = MyClass._loadConfiguration; than option 2: boolean xvalue = MyClass.LoadConfiguration();

Comment: Indeed, this applies to internal getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

static variables don't need get/set. You can always get them using className.staticVariable. get/set for static are always overhead.

Comment: Thanks thinksteep, i know that but i asking if there be a performance fault using a the option 1 or option 2 (I'm a C# programer and now starting with Android)